# How to get rspec-2 to give the full trace associated with a test failure?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, testing, rspec, rspec2

Right now if I run my test suite using `rake spec` I get an error:

```
1) SegmentsController GET 'index' should work
   Failure/Error: get 'index'
   undefined method `locale' for #
   # ./spec/controllers/segments_controller_spec.rb:14:
      in `block (3 levels) in '
```

This is normal as I do have an error :)

The problem is that the trace isn't very helpful. I know it broke in `segments_controller_spec.rb`, line 14, but this is just where I call the test:

```
### segments_controller_spec.rb:14
get 'index'
```

I would prefer to have the actual line breaking and the complete trace, not the part in the spec folder.

Running with `--trace` doesn't help.

Comment: Check http://spin.atomicobject.com/2010/12/28/rspec-backtrace-filtering/ There is a way to change default RSpec backtrace filtering

Answer (score 252, accepted):

You must run rspec with `-b` option to see full backtraces

Comment: I don't get it, neither this or the accepted answer give you backtrace further then from your spec file. Or it doesn't work only for me o_O

Comment: and fwiw if you use rspec with spork and guard you can create a .rspec file and add -b to it to get the output when you run your test suite

Comment: This is indeed the correct answer - you don't need the full backtrace (that includes stuff like rails and rspec and other gems) almost all of the time - the only time you ever need it is to debug or understand something caused by the gem itself.  So stick to the default backtrace clean patterns, and use -b in the odd case when you need it.

Comment: It didn't show stack trace info about the error itself. Rather, it showed the stack trace of the rspec gem

Comment: Works for RSpec 3 as well

Answer (score 29):

Another (easier) alternative is to edit the `.rspec` file, and add the `backtrace` option.
It should look somewhat like this:

```
--colour
--backtrace
```

That will give you the full backtrace.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes! this is exactly what I needed. stack trace to the actual error not the spec stack.

Comment: I believe the appropriate spelling is `color`. I think if you spell it `colour` a Monty Python joke might appear

Comment: Appropriate if you are from America. In the UK they write colour, and the rspec folks are so kind to allow both ;)

Comment: That's thrown a spanner in the bonnet!

Answer (score 6):

This will also work:

```
# rails_helper.rb
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.full_backtrace = true
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is to clear all backtrace exclusion patterns in `spec_helper.rb`. I like this solution most as I'm able to keep all RSpec settings in one place and get rid of `.rspec file` or explicit `--backtrace` in `.travis.yml`.

```
# spec_helper.rb
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.backtrace_exclusion_patterns = []
end
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to have that option in rspec 2.x.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to get the controller error to show up in rspec. Sometimes it shows up but I don't know what conditions cause it to show up. Here is a way to see the error fairly quickly though:

Open another terminal session and run:

```
tail -f log/test.log
```

Then go back to the terminal session and run just the spec that had the error:

```
bin/rspec -b spec/requests/posts/index_spec.rb
```

Go back to the tail of the log and you should see the error, hopefully without too much other stuff surrounding it (because you ran the failing test by itself).

Answer (score 0):

One more option when all else fails is to just add a rescue block and print out the stack try or add a binding pry statement there and use `show-stack`.

```
rescue Exception => e
  puts ""
  puts e.backtrace
  puts ""
```

Comment: This is sometimes the best option. Just make sure you remove it once you get it working. It should wrap the place where you expect the error to be. Perhaps put the `begin` and `rescue` block as the outer statement of the controller's action method. Or use `rescue_from`.

Comment: @bat yes this is a last resort attempt and like @bat said needs to be removed once you figured it out. Always remember to do your `git diff` before committing it will save your bacon.