# How to avoid a long stacktrace in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

is it easy way to limit stack trace only to files in application? Long stacktrace is messy and most errors are directly in app.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Normally the stacktrace is shortened automatically, unless you specify the option `--backtrace` in `.rspec` file.

Maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7649037/how-to-get-rspec-2-to-give-the-full-trace-associated-with-a-test-failure/7986714#7986714) is helpful for you. They try to achieve the opposite, but it shows the point where you can hook in and overrule it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is currently a way to further reduce the stacktrace, but I'm with you - it would be nice to be able to add something like `--backtrace 4` to .rspec that would limit it to 4 lines