# Why are my view specs behaving inconsistently?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm getting some strange results from view specs

```
Failure/Error: assert_select "div.fileinput-new.thumbnail"
ArgumentError:
  wrong number of arguments (3 for 1)
```

Ok, so this seems self explanatory (though I'm not sure what are the 3 arguments referenced).

However, if I run the suite again, I might get 0 errors. And the next, 5 errors, of the same type as above but referencing different DOM elements.

There is nothing fancy in any of these specs

```
describe do 
  build :object / create :object 
  @object = assign(:object, object )
  it 'displays the DOM elements' do 
    render
    asset_select #DOM_elements
  end
end
```

What could cause this kind of inconsistent coverage of view specs?

An example stack trace

```
Failure/Error: assert_select "div.fileinput-new.thumbnail"

     ArgumentError:
       wrong number of arguments (3 for 1)
     # /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@myapp/gems/actionview-4.2.6/lib/action_view/helpers/text_helper.rb:52:in `concat'
     # /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@myapp/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.2/lib/nokogiri/xml/searchable.rb:165:in `evaluate'
     # /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@myapp/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.2/lib/nokogiri/xml/searchable.rb:165:in `block in xpath'
     # /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@myapp/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.2/lib/nokogiri/xml/searchable.rb:156:in `map'
     # /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@myapp/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.2/lib/nokogiri/xml/searchable.rb:156:in `xpath'
     # /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@myapp/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.2/lib/nokogiri/xml/searchable.rb:193:in `css_internal'
     # /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@myapp/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.2/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:76:in `block in css'
     # /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@myapp/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.2/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:187:in `block in each'
     # /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@myapp/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.2/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:186:in `upto'
     # /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@myapp/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.2/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:186:in `each'
     # /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@myapp/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.2/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:75:in `inject'
     # /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@myapp/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.2/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:75:in `css'
     # /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@myapp/gems/rails-dom-testing-1.0.7/lib/rails/dom/testing/assertions/selector_assertions/html_selector.rb:20:in `select'
     # /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@myapp/gems/rails-dom-testing-1.0.7/lib/rails/dom/testing/assertions/selector_assertions.rb:174:in `assert_select'
     # ./spec/views/users/settings/profile.html.erb_spec.rb:24:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@myapp/gems/rails-dom-testing-1.0.7/lib/rails/dom/testing/assertions/selector_assertions.rb:295:in `nest_selection'
     # /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@myapp/gems/rails-dom-testing-1.0.7/lib/rails/dom/testing/assertions/selector_assertions.rb:177:in `block in assert_select'
     # /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@myapp/gems/rails-dom-testing-1.0.7/lib/rails/dom/testing/assertions/selector_assertions.rb:174:in `tap'
     # /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@myapp/gems/rails-dom-testing-1.0.7/lib/rails/dom/testing/assertions/selector_assertions.rb:174:in `assert_select'
     # ./spec/views/users/settings/profile.html.erb_spec.rb:22:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@myapp/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:236:in `instance_exec'
     # /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@myapp/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:236:in `block in run'
     # /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@myapp/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:478:in `block in with_around_and_singleton_context_hooks'
     # /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@myapp/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:435:in `block in with_around_example_hooks'
     # /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@myapp/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:478:in `block in run'
     # /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@myapp/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:618:in `block in run_around_example_hooks_for'
     # /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@myapp/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:320:in `call'
     # /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@myapp/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:320:in `call'
     # /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@myapp/gems/rspec-rails-3.4.2/lib/rspec/rails/adapters.rb:127:in `block (2 levels) in <module:MinitestLifecycleAdapter>'
     # /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@myapp/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:425:in `instance_exec'
     # /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@myapp/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:425:in `instance_exec'
     # /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@myapp/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:389:in `execute_with'
     # /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@myapp/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:620:in `block (2 levels) in run_around_example_hooks_for'
     # /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@myapp/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:320:in `call'
     # /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@myapp/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:320:in `call'
     # /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@myapp/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:621:in `run_around_example_hooks_for'
     # /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@myapp/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:478:in `run'
     # /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@myapp/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:435:in `with_around_example_hooks'
     # /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@myapp/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:478:in `with_around_and_singleton_context_hooks'
     # /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@myapp/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:233:in `run'
     # /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@myapp/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:581:in `block in run_examples'
     # /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@myapp/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:577:in `map'
     # /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@myapp/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:577:in `run_examples'
     # /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@myapp/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:543:in `run'
     # /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@myapp/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:544:in `block in run'
     # /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@myapp/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:544:in `map'
     # /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@myapp/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:544:in `run'
     # /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@myapp/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:119:in `block (3 levels) in run_specs'
     # /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@myapp/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:119:in `map'
     # /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@myapp/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:119:in `block (2 levels) in run_specs'
     # /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@myapp/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1680:in `with_suite_hooks'
     # /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@myapp/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:118:in `block in run_specs'
     # /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@myapp/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/reporter.rb:77:in `report'
     # /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@myapp/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:117:in `run_specs'
     # /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@myapp/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:93:in `run'
     # /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@myapp/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:78:in `run'
     # /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@myapp/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:45:in `invoke'
     # /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@myapp/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
     # /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@myapp/bin/rspec:23:in `load'
     # /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@myapp/bin/rspec:23:in `<main>'
     # /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@myapp/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
     # /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@myapp/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Can you provide the full stack trace? You might need to run rspec with the [`-b` option](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7653286/1544012).

Comment: thanks @BoraMa, I've added a trace. let me know if anything else would be useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a definitive answer: it appears that, for some weird reason, the [`evaluate` method](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/blob/master/lib/nokogiri/xml/searchable.rb#L165) in the Nokogiri's `Searchable` module considers the `concat()` function as a custom XPath function instead of the [internal XPath function](http://www.xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-xpathInternals.html#xmlXPathConcatFunction).

External XPath functions are [called as normal ruby methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8812293/1544012) in the context of the `handler` attribute of `evaluate`. Normally the handler is the [`SubstitutionContext` class](https://github.com/rails/rails-dom-testing/blob/master/lib/rails/dom/testing/assertions/selector_assertions/substitution_context.rb) but in your case it seems that sometimes this gets the context of the `TextHelper` module where the `concat` method is defined, accepting just 1 parameter (whereas the XPath's `concat()` function accepts any number of parameters). I think that this can lead to the errors you observe.

Could you open the `searchable.rb` file (see the stack trace for its location) on [this line](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/blob/master/lib/nokogiri/xml/searchable.rb#L165) and add before it some debug messages to inspect the contents of the following variables?

```
puts "ctx #{ctx.inspect}"
puts "path #{path.inspect}"
puts "handler #{handler.inspect}"
if handler.respond_to?(:concat)
  puts "concat #{handler.method(:concat).inspect}"
else
  puts "not responding to :concat"
end
```

Then, can you provide the output printed for one of the failing tests?

**Update:** the output showed that indeed the tests context was being polluted by the `ActionView::TextHelpers` module and in the end it turned out that there was a `ActionView::Helpers` module included in a model used in the tests.

Comment: thanks @BoraMa, I've added the full output to a gist: https://gist.github.com/ahharvey/ff87016bfaf48e0799cc0ef49a589db9. As the suite fails on a different test each time it is run, it's not clear to me which line is most relevant to this issue, hence I'm pasting all. This particular test run failed with: `Failure/Error: assert_select "input.btn.btn-primary.btn-lg[name=?][type=?]", "commit", "submit" ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (3 for 1) `

Comment: the last line in the gist may be the key, but appreciate your thoughts.

Comment: Hmm, I'm glad the output proved that my guess was right! The ruby `concat` method is defined in [this](https://gist.github.com/ahharvey/ff87016bfaf48e0799cc0ef49a589db9#file-nokogiri_trace-L1039) test run and all further tests, because the `handler` gets set to nil and the current context gets polluted with the `TextHelper` module for some reason. However it's still a mystery to me why...

Comment: Can you search all your tests for lines where there is an argument, that is not of the `Hash`, `String` or `Symbol` class, passed to the `assert_select` method? It might even be `nil` or anything else but hash, string, or symbol. I'm asking because it seems that arguments of other classes may be interpreted as the `handler`.

Comment: bearing in mind this is an inherited test suite, the only non Hash, String or Symbol asset_select cases appear to be Integers (e.g., `assert_select "td", :text => 1.to_s, :count => 2`), empty strings (e.g., `assert_select "td", :text => "".to_s, :count => 2`) and path_helpers (e.g., `assert_select "form", :action => objects_path`). Thanks for your thoughts

Comment: No, these are all hashes and now I think this was a false idea, sorry. Nevertheless, I found out something: I get very similar errors if I try to `include ActionView::Helpers` in my view test. Can you check your tests for such includes? If you find some, can you comment them out to see it something changes?

Comment: No specs `include ActionView::Helpers`, however this line was included in a model for some reason. After removing the include, the view tests appear to now be working. You are a genius! Thanks for spending time on this and for your help!

Comment: Oh, this is so great to hear, I was beginning to be running out of ideas! :) Most probably this model has been used in one of the view tests and this `include` polluted the test's context. I updated the answer with this probable explanation.